# Indirect site navigation via sections of my front page - bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, navigation, ux, section

I am experimenting with constructing a "user journey" via navigable sections on my front page, as discussed by [this answer over in the UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/28743/53990).

Unfortunately, the scope of the site (it is for a large, open-source software project) means that I cannot - and probably should not - put all the content on a single page.

So, my plan was to have the front page consist of sections that can be navigated by the top navigation bar.  Within these on-page sections would be plenty of images and a few lines of text, followed by a button that links to a separate, more in-depth page.

This seems like a good user experience - they get the general gist without too much clutter - but I am worried that Google won't understand the structure because the pages won't be linked via a traditional `ul/li` navigation menu.

Is this structure a problem for SEO?  Would it help to add a more traditional navigation menu in the footer?

Here is a rough idea of my plan: http://www.userfrosting.com/0.3.0/

[This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60231/is-it-advisable-to-combine-a-single-with-a-multi-page-site) addresses the UX aspect of this format, but not the indexibility.

Comment: Can you give us example code just to be sure we are giving you the straight skinny?? Otherwise, you are leaving it up to our imaginations- and some us are nuts!! ;-) I am not telling tales out of school... I just want to be absolutely correct trying to answer a question like this. Cheers!!

Comment: Yup, just added a link.  The buttons are placeholders right now, but the idea is that they'll link to external pages.

Comment: No you should be fine. Keep in mind that Google is not grading your work. They want to index your site and have it perform well. For what it is worth, links are read in top-bottom, left-right order and processed that way. In this way, your links will be read, but they will not be related necessarily- but that is not really a criteria for success in search. In your case, it is not likely you want them to appear as navigation anyway. However, the page is devoid of content and will never really rank as it stands. Text is required for that.